# Add a button to sharepoint library

Tags: sharepoint-designer, document-library, ootb

I have been assigned a task to work on document libraries. The requirements of the project want me to make a view of doclibs that shows the last 10 modified documents and that view should have a little button/widget to link to the folder showing view. How can I make such a button that would sit next to the sync feature of a document library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way to do that is by using JSLink and attach to the current view. In the js file that you are going to use in the JSLink, you can use jQuery and target the following `UL` with this class `ms-qcb-zone ms-qcb-leftzone` (This ul contains the New, Upload, Sync, etc) . You can add an `li` at the end with the button you want with link to the view.

[image]

Comment: where do you find the class "ms-qcb-zone ms-qcb-leftzone" at?

Comment: updated my answer with a screen shot. Basically, open up The Developer Tools and hover over the sync feature and go to the container UL (one indicated by the arrow)

Comment: I really appreciate your help, I created a new button called "GO". My question is, using the dev tools can you change where the link takes you? Also, would it be okay to save this as a template and have all of them use the button?

Comment: Option1you can add it to your master page (link to js script, but this will run on all document libraries which might not be desired)

Comment: I'm okay with changing it on the master page to reflect all libraries, where at should I edit the master ?

Comment: open you master page using SPD and look for the <SharePoint:ScriptLink /> section, add another Script <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="https://mysite.sharepoint.com/site/script.js" runat="server" Localizable="false"/> and inside this file, you would create a self invoking function or use jquery document ready function that will inject a li under that UL with the link....

Comment: One last question! I got the scriptlink section in the master page I'm running, but I am by no means a JS ninja. I know I want to create a function that adds a Li to the list but I'm not sure the naming conventions of sharepoint for the list buttons.

Comment: it will be something like this : $(".ms-listview-qcbContainer ul").append('<li class="ms-qcb-item"><a href="#">my button</a></li>');...use the console on Chrome Developer Tools (highly recommended) and see how it will look and tweak it with css to look the way you want...dont forget to mark it as an answer if you think this has resolved the issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39644/discussion-between-sabien-ambrose-and-ahmed-mahmoud).

Answer (score 2):

Alternate solution,

1. Open site in designer
2. Navigate to List and Libraries
3. click on library name
4. Right bottom - Custom actions - New
5. Provide button name, description
6. Provide url of your view in Navigate to URL
7. Provide image url and sequesnce number as to where you want the ribbon button to be viewed.

Comment: I know i can put a button in the ribbon but that isn't an intuitive feel when this is being built for non- tech savvy individuals. Is there any way to add a button next to the doclib name or under it?